# Error while hosting .net core 3.0 in IIS (0x8007000D)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, iis, hosting

I created a website and it has the following web.config file. It is running in .net core 3.0 Self contained published version. It was running ago in Windows 7 now my company updated to windows 10 and now it stopped working. It is same IIS configuration but can't read the web.config file. I tried other solutions mentioned but I will love to have your support. It is giving error stating IIS can't load the webconfig file.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\ASU_Statistics.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCODE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="44370" />
          <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: ee398fc0-8f34-4edf-9353-67342cbe9ee3-->
```

[image: This Image shows the error I received]

Comment: Tons of common causes, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html#background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the `AspNetCoreModuleV2` module is installed on server.

If module is not installed download `AspNetCoreModuleV2` from this [link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-2.2.2-windows-hosting-bundle-installer) and install

Comment: Thank you !!! I didn't notice that it was version 2.2.7 I got it installed, It is running fine 
Thank you !!!